# Ansible not loading the "all" group variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a very simple Ansible setup.

**`group_vars/all/main.yml`**:

```
symfony:
    env: prod
    owner: capistrano
    cache_owner: files
    cache_group: files
    deploy_base: /opt/symfony
    keep_count: 2
```

**`deploy.yml`**:

```
# ...
  - name: roll forward latest release
    symfony_preload: version="{{ symfony.deploy_version }}" deploy_base="{{ symfony.deploy_base }}"
```

This modules does, in fact, work, it's that Ansible doesn't seem to be loading variables properly. I'm calling Ansible like this:

```
/usr/bin/ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i inventory/hosts \
    -e deploy_hosts=stg-web \
    -e symfony.deploy_version="$UPSTREAM_BUILD_NUMBER" \
    -e symfony.env="stg"
```

This fails:

```
TASK [roll forward latest release] *********************************************
fatal: [webserver1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'symfony' is undefined"}
```

What's failing here? Is Ansible wiping out my variables with its own from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things needed:

1. Specify `hash_behaviour = merge` in ansible.cfg
2. Pass the hash --extra-var in JSON format:

   `→ ansible-playbook playbooks/variables-demo.yml -e '{"symfony": {"deploy_version": "y", "deploy_base": "/some/other" } }'`

Comment: Thanks! Kind of silly that merge isn't by default in Ansible when working with hash vars.

Answer (score 1):

`hash_behaviour = merge` is not a recommended and prefer way of doing thing. I can show you the more elegant way of doing this:

**`group_vars/all/main.yml:`**

```
symfony:
    env: "{{ ENV }}"
    owner: capistrano
    cache_owner: files
    cache_group: files
    deploy_base: /opt/symfony
    keep_count: 2
    deploy_version: "{{ DEPLOY_VERSION }}"
    deploy_hosts: "{{ DEPLOY_HOSTS }}"
```

Then call your Ansible like this:

```
/usr/bin/ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i inventory/hosts \
    -e "DEPLOY_HOSTS=stg-web" \
    -e "DEPLOY_VERSION$UPSTREAM_BUILD_NUMBER" \
    -e "ENV=stg"
```

Hope that will help you!

Comment: Why is it not a recommended/preferred way of doing things? It makes perfect sense and should be the default behavior IMO.